# Create dataset in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dataset

In Python, I would like to create a dataset composed of 3 columns containing RGB colors:

```
    R    G    B
0   0    0    0
1   0    0    8
2   0    0    16
3   0    0    24
...
31  0    0    248
32  0    8    0
33  0    8    8
...
```

Of course, I could use 3 nested for-loops, but I wonder if there is not a more optimal solution.

```
for R in range(0,255,8):
    for G in range(0,255,8):
        for B in range(0,255,8):
            # ... Do something here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `itertool.product()`.

```
import itertools
it = itertools.product(range(0, 255, 8), range(0, 255, 8), range(0, 255, 8))
```

The result is huge that's why I am putting it at 10 values.

```
print(list(it)[:10])
# Output
# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 8), (0, 0, 16), (0, 0, 24), (0, 0, 32),
#  (0, 0, 40), (0, 0, 48), (0, 0, 56), (0, 0, 64), (0, 0, 72)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the RGB color codes using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), then pass that to [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to put it into a `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
l = range(0, 255, 8)
rgb = [[r, g, b] for r in l for g in l for b in l]
df = pd.DataFrame(rgb, columns=['R', 'G', 'B'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         R    G    B
0        0    0    0
1        0    0    8
2        0    0   16
3        0    0   24
4        0    0   32
...    ...  ...  ...
32763  248  248  216
32764  248  248  224
32765  248  248  232
32766  248  248  240
32767  248  248  248

[32768 rows x 3 columns]
```

Though using the range `range(0, 255, 8)` will end at 248, so if you want to end at 255, then use `range(0, 257, 8)` instead.